# GCP Vertex AI Service Agent access to GCR image Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am getting the below error.
Does anyone have any idea how to solve it?

```
Failed to create pipeline job. Error: Vertex AI Service Agent 
'XXXXX@gcp-sa-aiplatform-cc.iam.gserviceaccount.com' should be granted
 access to the image gcr.io/gcp-project-id/application:latest
```

Comment: According to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control) , you can give roles/storage.objectViewer, roles/storage.legacyBucketWriter and roles/storage.admin to your service account to access your image in Container Registry using the service-account.

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Comment: i tried same thing it didn't work for me how did you solve it rituraj / shipra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{PROJECT_NUMBER}@gcp-sa-aiplatform-cc.iam.gserviceaccount.com` is google's [AI Platform service agent](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-agents).
This Service agent requires access to read/pull the docker image from your project's gcr to create container for pipeline run.

If You have permission to edit [IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles), You can try adding [Artifact Registry roles](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control#roles) to the above service agent.
You can start with adding `roles/artifactregistry.reader`.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Dont forget to check the "Include Google Provided role grants" button to view the vertex AI service agent

Answer (score 0):

This error may have occurred due to missing roles or permissions for pulling and pushing images into Container Registry. All the users and service accounts must be given appropriate permissions  for Cloud Storage who interact with Container Registry. You can give  roles/storage.objectViewer, roles/storage.legacyBucketWriter and roles/storage.admin to your service account to access your image in Container Registry using the service-account. You can follow this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control) for giving appropriate roles and permissions to the Service Account.